# SKProductRequest unable to retrieve products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I am working with `SKProduct` which was working correctly.
Suddenly today `SKProductRequest` is unable to retrieve the products and is not calling any of the delegate methods of `self.products`.

I have change my app name and added description in iTunes Connect. What effect does that have on in-app purchases?

Here is my code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *validProducts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;

-(void)fetchAvailableProducts
{
   NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.fitin15month.product",@"com.fitin15.year",nil];
   productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
   productsRequest.delegate = self;
   [productsRequest start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = (int)[response.products count];
    if (count>0)
    {
            //Perform Action
    }
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     //Perform Stuff
}
```

Please let me know whether it's an issue with the code or iTunes Connect.

Comment: If you are in sandbox environment you could retry later.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll try it